# Bootstrap 4 Relative Positioning

Tags: html, css

So i want to position something 10px - 100px to the right. But the problem is i can't do that when it should be responsive. I use Bootstrap 4 and when i use something like position: relative it isn't responsive anymore and if you now use it on mobile it won't work and if you resize the page it will look weird too. I want that the copyright logo is at the bottom and the navigation bar is under Mr. Shisha. [Heres what i got so far](https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-cache-7kr9h). Thanks!

Comment: For the positioning problem show the css code hope we can help you.
And coming to second issue Use **media query** (check the link below) which will help you for the resizing of the page. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Comment: When you click on the link you come to the CSS Code and HTML! And Thanks!

Comment: So can you help me?

Comment: Click on the Link: https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-cache-7kr9h There is the CSS.